# R: How to give the same id number to each person in a data frame based on a different data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have two data sets, df and df2. This is an oversimplified version of two very large and messy data frames.

In the original df, I created a unique id for each person by grouping them by belt and weight. I want the same id numbers each person has in df to be given to the same people in df2. They need to have the same name, and should be grouped by belt and weight. Note that there are people in df2 who are not in df.

The simplified df looks something like below

```
     belt     weight rank id        name
1  purple open class    1 55  Tom Cruise
2   black    rooster    2 79 Emma Watson
3    blue    feather    3 63    John Doe
4    blue    feather    4 63    John Doe
5  purple open class    5 55  Tom Cruise
6   brown      heavy    6  3  James Bond
7  purple open class    7 55  Tom Cruise
8  purple      heavy    8 61  Tom Cruise
9   black open class    9 70    Jane Doe
10 purple      heavy   10 61  Tom Cruise
```

The second data frame looks something like this. A person who is in df2, but not in df should receive an NA for their id. Note that the id's must be given by belt and weight because some people have different points depending on which weight division they competed in

```
    belt2    weight2 rank2        name points
1  purple open class     1  Tom Cruise    100
2   black    rooster     2 Emma Watson     30
3    blue    feather     3    John Doe     50
4    blue    feather     4    John Doe     50
5  purple open class     5  Tom Cruise    100
6   brown      heavy     6  James Bond    200
7   black    rooster     7    Jon Snow     92
8  purple      heavy     8  Tom Cruise     77
9   black open class     9    Jane Doe     88
10 purple      heavy    10  Tom Cruise     77
```

This is what I would like df2 to look like:

```
    belt2    weight2 rank2 id           name points
1  purple open class     1 55     Tom Cruise    100
2   black    rooster     2 79    Emma Watson     30
3    blue    feather     3 63       John Doe     50
4    blue    feather     4 63       John Doe     50
5  purple open class     5 55     Tom Cruise    100
6   brown      heavy     6  3     James Bond    200
7   black    rooster     7 NA       Jon Snow     92
8  purple      heavy     8 61     Tom Cruise     77
9   black open class     9 70       Jane Doe     88
10 purple      heavy    10 61     Tom Cruise     77
```

Basically, I want the id numbers in df2 to match the id numbers in df. If there is not a match, fill with NA.

```
# df
belt <- c("purple", "black", "blue", "blue", "purple", "brown", "purple", "purple", "black", "purple")
weight <- c("open class", "rooster", "feather", "feather", "open class", "heavy", "open class", "heavy", "open class", "heavy")
rank <- 1:10
id <- c(55, 79, 63, 63, 55, 3, 55, 61, 70, 61)
names <- c("Tom Cruise", "Emma Watson", "John Doe", "John Doe", "Tom Cruise", "James Bond", "Tom Cruise", "Tom Cruise", "Jane Doe", "Tom Cruise")
(df <- data.frame(belt, weight, rank, id, name = names))

#df2
belt2 <- c("purple", "black", "blue", "blue", "purple", "brown", "black", "purple", "black", "purple")
weight2 <- c("open class", "rooster", "feather", "feather", "open class", "heavy", "rooster", "heavy", "open class", "heavy")
rank2 <- 1:10
names2 <- c("Tom Cruise", "Emma Watson", "John Doe", "John Doe", "Tom Cruise", "James Bond", "Jon Snow", "Tom Cruise", "Jane Doe", "Tom Cruise")
points <- c(100, 30, 50, 50, 100, 200, 92, 77, 88, 77)
(df2 <- data.frame(belt2, weight2, rank2, name = names2, points))
```

Comment: Are you looking for base `merge` or `dplyr::right_join`?

Comment: I'm not looking for a merge just yet. I need them to have the same id's first.

Comment: @bandcar That is exactly what a merge does.. right? I suggest you read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: I fully understand how the merging works. This is a very messy data set, so I cannot do the merge at this point. In fact, I've inquired four times on stackoverflow asking for assistance merging some of the actual 14 data sets, but I never got a response. That's never happened to me here before. The mess that goes along with the real data set is too extensive to list out here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved with a right join and removing the duplicates after it. I will use base function `merge`.

```r
df3 <- merge(
  df, df2, 
  by.x = c("belt", "weight", "rank", "name"), 
  by.y = c("belt2", "weight2", "rank2", "name"),
  all.y = TRUE
)
df3 <- df3[!duplicated(df3),]
df3[order(df3$rank),]
#>      belt     weight rank        name id points
#> 9  purple open class    1  Tom Cruise 55    100
#> 2   black    rooster    2 Emma Watson 79     30
#> 4    blue    feather    3    John Doe 63     50
#> 5    blue    feather    4    John Doe 63     50
#> 10 purple open class    5  Tom Cruise 55    100
#> 6   brown      heavy    6  James Bond  3    200
#> 3   black    rooster    7    Jon Snow NA     92
#> 7  purple      heavy    8  Tom Cruise 61     77
#> 1   black open class    9    Jane Doe 70     88
#> 8  purple      heavy   10  Tom Cruise 61     77
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

A `dplyr` right join is

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
})

df %>%
  right_join(df2, 
             by = c("belt" = "belt2", "weight" = "weight2", "rank" = "rank2"),
             suffix = c(".x", "")) %>%
  select(-name.x) %>%
  arrange(rank)
#>      belt     weight rank id        name points
#> 1  purple open class    1 55  Tom Cruise    100
#> 2   black    rooster    2 79 Emma Watson     30
#> 3    blue    feather    3 63    John Doe     50
#> 4    blue    feather    4 63    John Doe     50
#> 5  purple open class    5 55  Tom Cruise    100
#> 6   brown      heavy    6  3  James Bond    200
#> 7   black    rooster    7 NA    Jon Snow     92
#> 8  purple      heavy    8 61  Tom Cruise     77
#> 9   black open class    9 70    Jane Doe     88
#> 10 purple      heavy   10 61  Tom Cruise     77
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this task by using a `left join` between the two dataframes.

```
df2 = df2 %>% left_join(df, by = c("belt2" = "belt", "weight2" = "weight", "name" = "name")) %>% select(belt2, weight2, rank2, name, points, id)

    belt2    weight2 rank2        name points id
1  purple open class     1  Tom Cruise    100 55
2  purple open class     1  Tom Cruise    100 55
3  purple open class     1  Tom Cruise    100 55
4   black    rooster     2 Emma Watson     30 79
5    blue    feather     3    John Doe     50 63
6    blue    feather     3    John Doe     50 63
7    blue    feather     4    John Doe     50 63
8    blue    feather     4    John Doe     50 63
9  purple open class     5  Tom Cruise    100 55
10 purple open class     5  Tom Cruise    100 55
11 purple open class     5  Tom Cruise    100 55
12  brown      heavy     6  James Bond    200  3
13  black    rooster     7    Jon Snow     92 NA
14 purple      heavy     8  Tom Cruise     77 61
15 purple      heavy     8  Tom Cruise     77 61
16  black open class     9    Jane Doe     88 70
17 purple      heavy    10  Tom Cruise     77 61
18 purple      heavy    10  Tom Cruise     77 61
```